# C++ pointer to a class method call

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

In my class Tabla I have a public pointer to method:

```
public:
    int (Tabla :: *punterofunc)(int,int);
```

In main I point it to a class method:

```
tablita.punterofunc = &Tabla :: in_lineal;
```

But this call doesn't work!

```
 tablita->punterofunc(num,0);
```

Comment: What the exception / error do you receive?

Comment: /home/freinn/Desktop/tablashash/main.cpp|29|error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Tabla’|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this tasty syntax:

```
((tablita).*(tablita.punterofunc))(num,0);
```

`tablita.punterofunc` is a member function pointer. The general syntax for calling a pointer-to-member-function `p` on an object `o` is:

```
((o).*(p))(args...);
```

Just apply that to your code. (Some of the parens might not be necessary in all cases (not sure), but if you stick with that, it should work all the time.)

Comment: What? Is there no syntatic sugar for this? I could hardly call this tasty.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5 - that's one of the only cases where the C++FAQ advises using a macro to make the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tablita.*punterofunc(num,0);
```

Comment: I've done but.../home/freinn/Desktop/tablashash/main.cpp|29|error: ‘punterofunc’ was not declared in this scope|